# Qual a combinação de table e float?

Tags: html, css

Todo mundo que mexe com programação web já passou por isso:

```css
.children {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="children">
    Teste
  </div>
</div>
```

Se vocês usarem o Inspect Element acima podem notar que no elemento `.parent` o `height` é `0px`.

Nunca li por qual motivo isso acontece. Isso faz parte da pergunta, se alguém souber e puder explicar, seria bom.

Mas o que eu faço para resolver isso ? Algo que eu aprendi há um tempo, para não ter que usar o `clear: both`:

```css
.parent {
  display: table;
}
.children {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="children">
    Teste
  </div>
</div>
```

Podem notar agora que o elemento `.parent` tem a mesma altura que o `.children`, mesmo com `float`. Embora já faça isso há um tempo e me ajuda muito, gostaria de saber porque isso acontece.

1. Qual o efeito de `table` em `float` ?
2. E quando não se faz isso porque o elemento pai fica com `height: 0px` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) O efeito de `table` em `float` não é nenhum, só que `table` tem outro display (table) ao contrário do `display: block` da div. Como `table` sempre foi usado para ter elementos dentro o display desta *tem a altura do conteúdo*

Isto faz com que o flow dos elementos seja um bocadinho diferente, o que afecta por vez os elementos filhos de maneira diferente.

2) Uma div cujos filhos sejam só elementos com float perde a altura *porque a alternativa é feia de mais*: pensa, se o elemento só contém floats e o elemento pai tivesse altura haveria de acontecer uma grande linha (de uma cor qq) com uma height enorme com elementos em cada ponta do site (esq. e direito)

Assim, sem altura, ninguém percebe que existe um elemento (isto, se usares uma div).

Comment: `display: table` substitui o `clear: both` no caso de definir um sistema de grids como no bootstrap, com as colunas flutuantes?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss não, o `clear` é para *quando sabes onde os elementos vão estar*. Sendo que o `display: table` faz uma *tabela* e essa tabela *tem conteudo* a tabela fica com a height dos filhos

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss o bootstrap usa `margin` para 'flutuar' as colunas

Answer (score 0):

O `float` originalmente  foi criado para as imagens flutuarem nos textos.

E quando se faz isso, o elemento filho 'flutua' no pai, ou seja se o pai não tem nenhum tamanho definido ele fica zerado que é por default.

Talvez isso seja mais completo pra você: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805352/floatleft-vs-displayinline-vs-displayinline-block-vs-displaytable-cell

Comment: Você quer dizer que o default height é 0 ?

Comment: @MagicHat da `div` sim

Comment: Eu tava achando que height  default é `auto`...

Comment: @MagicHat Eu sei.. talvez me expressei de forma incorreta, quis dizer que se não definir nada sua altura é zero!